# What is the meaning of dollar with angle brackets in CMake 3.11

Tags: cmake

Here is an example script from [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html):

```
target_link_libraries(myExe lib1 lib2 lib3)
target_include_directories(myExe
  PRIVATE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:lib3,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
```

What is the meaning of `$<>` here? Can it be substituted with `${}` ?

Comment: See also [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). And no, you can't replace them with normal variable expansion.

Comment: @Florian Thanks, that partially answers my question.